# Different pages in one page and their events

Tags: html

I am displaying 1 html page in another page. I am not using frames. Rather I took advantage of javascript and  to display the different page in a page. Here with I am giving sample code of how I display the web page in another web page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>     
    <style>
        #headerDiv{         
            top: 0;
            width: 100%
            display: block;
            //border-bottom: 3px solid #808080;
        }
        #headerHR{                                              
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
        }
        #headerImg{
            float: left;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        #headerPre{
            float: left;
            font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        #navDiv{
            position: absolute;             
        }
        #gapFillerDiv{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){               
                    $('#sensors').load('./nav.html');
           });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="headerDiv">
        <img id="headerImg" src="./assets/dummyLogo.png" width="280" height="125" alt="DummyLogo"/>
        <pre id="headerPre">
                 Test Series
        Test Solutions
        </pre>                  
        <hr id="headerHR">
    </div>      
    <p id="test"></p>
    <div id="sensors"  style="position: fixed; top: 138px;"></div>      
</body>
```

In the above code I am displaying a web page nav.html in a page called test.html. In nav.html there is a simple button. I want to view the result of button click of nav.html page displayed in test.html page in test.html page itself. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a button click handler like any other.

Since the button is added to the page after the DOM loads, the simplest way to do this is to make use of jQuery's `.on()` with an additional selector.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourButton', function () {
    // your handler
});
```

Just replace `#yourButton` with whatever the selector to identify your button would be.  The way this works is that the click handler is actually attached to `document` and can be invoked for *any* click anywhere in the document, but the second selector as an argument to `.on()` is a filter applied to click event originators *at the time the event is invoked* so that it would apply only to the target element(s).

I've written something a little more in depth about this [here](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html), as I'm sure many others have as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('#sensors').on('click','button',function(){
   alert('button click in #sensors wrapper');
});
```